# Calling Accept() second time gives new socket for the same client request

Tags: c, sockets

I like to write a server program with two threads, one thread for accepting requests and queuing them. Second one, worker thread, for processing them (I have not written this yet). Here is the pseudo code.

```
    while (1) {

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    read_from_newsockfd()
    put_in_queue  

    // I am not closing the newsockfd here. If I close it here how 
to I communicate with the client from my second worker thread.
    }
```

Now when I send the request from browser, accept() gets called second time giving another socket for the same request without blocking. I tried sending second request from different browser, I got segmentation fault. Could any one please tell me how to approach this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "another socket for the same request"? You'll call `accept()` and it will block *until* there is a second request...

Comment: For the first time it blocked. In second iteration, it should block at the accept() since no other client is trying for connection. But accept() get executed giving different newsockfd, with the very same request parameters I have in first request.

Comment: Is it possible that the browser is trying to fetch favicon.ico?

Comment: Or any other resources (images, etc) that are on the requested webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the browser is making multiple requests, in particular for /favicon.ico as well as the HTML?

I suggest you use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to see what's going on at the network level.

Comment: I checked it with firebug. I see only one request.

Comment: @Lamia: Did you also try it with Wireshark? I would trust that over firebug, personally...

Comment: @JS : No not yet. I'm using ubuntu so have little difficulty installing it. I might have to use it with wine. I'll try.

Comment: @Lamia: You can still run the *server* in Ubuntu - just run Wireshark on a machine with the browser. (It'll make life easier if you separate the client and server machines, to take the loopback adapter out of the picture.)

Comment: @JS: Thanks a lot. I've installed it and trying that. I'll let you know the outcome once I finish it.

Comment: @Lamia: Cool. I won't be online for a little while, but I'll look forward to seeing the results of your investigations.

Comment: @JS: I just finished understanding the outcome. [RST, ACK] was sent back from the server to the browser. With firefox it happened only once. With Google Chrome it happened multiple times for a single request. Actual request along with [PSH, ACK] was sent exactly twice. Once for firefox. Once for Google Chrome. This indicates there are no multiple requests

Comment: @Lamia: In that case I'm confused :(

Comment: @JS: I finally observed that its browser behavior. When no response is received from server Google chrome tries to send same request second time (I see SYN but not PSH) (might be sever times, after second request my server crashes),where as firefox sits there just running the little ring. Thanks for the nice tool, I am begining to understand networking :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your client is sending multiple requests for multiple resources?

Comment: No it should not. I'm just asking for simple index.html with "Hello world"